# Adding a unordered list in a ordered list

Tags: html, list

I am trying to put a (unordered list tag> in a (ordered list) list tag in HTML5 if anyone can help? It does display in browser correct but W3C Validator is showing an error. This is the error it is showing: Element ul not allowed as child of element ol in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Thankyou

Comment: How should we know what's wrong with your HTML if you don't show it?

Answer (score 4):

Put the list in a list element, e.g.

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <ul>...</ul>
       ...
    </li>
    ...
</ol>
```